# Create multi statement instructions in TWIG

Tags: twig

I wonder if there is a way of creating multi statements in TWIG

Example: two separate statements ...

```
{% set foo:bar %}
{% set baz:qux %}
```

into one single statement

```
{%
    set foo:bar 
    set baz:qux
%}
```

Comment: great question, btw the doc refer, for the [set operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html), that is possible to do this: `{% set foo, bar = 'foo', 'bar' %}`
  in the same section the example is that is equivalent to the double code block. So, seem is not possbile...

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. `set` is a "tag", all thing after are compiled with the Token Parser for the "tag".